# Transmit SFTP : can't upload file error

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm using Transmit for Mac as SFTP. It was working properly. Suddenly it started showing this error when I try to upload or edit any 
file [image]

How can I solve this Error?

Here's what the console is showing :
[image]

Comment: Do you not have any more information about the error??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, some Console log? Open your Console.app and search by transmit...

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot of what the console is showing when trying to upload a file using Transmit.

Answer (score 0):

I traced the problem using Terminal and I found that the server was full.